# Sharepoint 2013- Customization of OOOB Picture Library Slideshow Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have created OOOB slider webpart as below in picture 1 , how to customize it same as in picture 2 with below options
1-previous image icon
2-next image icon
3-image pager in center

```
                                 **Picture 1**
```

[image]

```
                                  **Picture 2**
```

[image]